# VirtualizingStackPanel is fast only when fresh. How can I fix it?

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualization, virtualizingstackpanel

When I create `ListBox` with virtualization enabled and then update all its items appearance it works very fast. But when i slowly scroll down all items in `ListBox` and then update all items appearance it takes a lot of time. I think it because `VirtualizingStackPanel` does not destroy items when they are runs out of viewport.
I wrote simple app to reproduce this behavior.

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) // creating 5k text boxes
            MyList.Items.Add(new TextBox() { Text = CurrText });
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        n = (n + 1) % 2; // switch 0 to 1 or 1 to 0
        foreach (var item in MyList.Items)
            ((TextBox)item).Text = CurrText; // set new text
    }

    static int n = 0;
    string CurrText { get { return new string(n.ToString()[0], 50); } }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="MyList" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="UpdateText" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Clicking a button "UpdateText" updates all textboxes text. If slowly scroll to end by dragging scroller, "UpdateText" button clicks with a huge lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create `TextBoxes` manually.

> The word "virtualize" refers to a technique by which a subset of user interface (UI) elements are generated from a larger number of data items based on which items are visible on-screen. **Generating many UI elements when only a few elements might be on the screen can adversely affect the performance of your application**.

You create your UI items manually so it's already too late for virtualization. Use bindings and it will create `TextBox` from `ItemTemplate` whenever it is required. It will also not refresh `TextBox.Text` value if it's not currently in the view. To do that change your `MainWindow` to create `ObservableCollection` instead of `TextBoxes` and operate on that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _textBoxes = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ICollection<string> TextBoxes { get { return _textBoxes; } }

    private int n = 0;
    private string CurrText { get { return new string(n.ToString()[0], 50); } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) _textBoxes.Add(CurrText);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        n = (n + 1) % 2; // switch 0 to 1 or 1 to 0
        for (int i = 0; i < _textBoxes.Count; i++) _textBoxes[i] = CurrText;
    }
}
```

and then change XAML to bind to `TextBoxes` list property

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxes}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="UpdateText" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```